# Javascript not setting the value of a select (Only sometimes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ajax request and in the success I'm trying to set the value to a select, like this:

```
 $('#cadastro .ui-content #cpEstado').val(cadastro.IdentificadorEstado);
 alert(cadastro.IdentificadorEstado + ", " + $("#cpEstado").val());
```

Like i said it's within the success section of the request, the alert is bringing the value of cadastro.IdentificadorEstado everytime, but the $("#cpEstado").val() is comming as null most of the time. Just in case I tried setting async to false unsuccessfully. And I also tried using

```
document.getElementById('cpEstado').value = cadastro.IdentificadorEstado;
```

but also didn't work. What could it be?

```
  <div class="ui-block-a uf">
       <label for="cpEstado" class="select">
             <select name="estado" id="cpEstado" data-theme="c">
                   <option value="" disabled selected>UF</option>
             </select>
       </label>
  </div>
```

Edit1: This is a select element.

Edit2: When the page loads, the option that has the same value that I'm bringing with the request and setting to the select element should be selected. Sometimes it's being selected, sometimes it's not.

Comment: Please post relevant html snippets in your question too.

Comment: Trigger a `change` event: `.trigger("change")` after `.val(...)`

Answer (score 2):

you need to do:

```
 $('#cadastro .ui-content #cpEstado').val(cadastro.IdentificadorEstado);
 $('#cadastro .ui-content #cpEstado').change();
```

or shorthand:

```
$('#cadastro .ui-content #cpEstado').val(cadastro.IdentificadorEstado).change();
```

also you don't need to specify that long selector, if element has it's own `id` you can refer to it directly via id because id is unique in whole html document, so instead of writing

```
$('#cadastro .ui-content #cpEstado')
```

you can just write

```
$('#cpEstado')
```

and it should have same result, note that it will have different behavior when selector isn't `id` but some other

Comment: I tried using the change event as you said, but it didn't work either.

Comment: so let's simplify what you want to achieve - you download some data, and get `ID` of element and then mark item with `value` property equal to `ID` you download as currently selected, right? or you download name of item?

Comment: Actually, I set the value when the page is loading so I also tried using the load(), but also unsuccessfully.

Comment: stetoc Yes, I brought the data from a webserver through an ajax request, put it into an object (cadastro) and tried to pass the value of an attribute (cadastro.IdentificadorEstado) to this element. It happens when the page loads.

Comment: I'm sure, the value of cadastro.IdentificadorEvento is always right, the problem is only when setting the value to this select element. I fill other elements with values from the same object and they're doing ok.

Comment: you want to add new item into select or make item that currently is in select selected?

Comment: I want to pass the val to the select element to make the option of the same value selected. The value is the id of the option.